# Multi column flyout menu

Tags: css, html, javascript

I want to build a horizontal menu bar with a multi column flyout of the hovered item. It should be done with html lists, css and javascript (if needed) only.
There should be a max height of the flyout so that the following ul's automatically break into the next column.

An example of the mentioned navigation can be found on the [italian microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/it/it/default.aspx) (first navigation point called "Windows").

Comment: This question amounts "show me the codez" and is likely to be closed. If you wish to avoid this I would recommend editing it to highlight specific areas that you are having difficulty implementing.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Looks like a dropdown menu to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sitepoint [Mega Dropdown Menu with jQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/31/make-a-mega-drop-down-menu-with-jquery/) is a great tutorial, and it has served me well. The way these things work is by using a `div` container as the dropdown, so whatever you put in it, e.g., the multicolumn list, would be up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/

Answer (score 0):

A nice, big repository of different CSS-menus can be found here:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/

Be aware: "If you are using this on a commercial web site, or as a paying job for a client, then please email me asking for permission" (Stu Nicholls)